# How to correctly reload .vimrc file so it will be equal to restart of vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I use MacVim and in my .vimrc file I have `map ,V :source $MYVIMRC<CR>` binding that allows me to apply the newest version of `.vimrc` in a case it was recently modified. 
However I noticed that strange things can happen, relaunch can slow down vim and some plugins can start to conflict after pressing `,V`, when everything works fine if I just close and relaunch MacVim from the scratch.

I'd be very thankful if you could give me a hint on the reason of this behavior as I'd like to have a possibility to update `.vimrc` file that will completely clear internal vim state and grab new configuration file

Comment: The only way to *"completely clear internal vim state and grab new configuration file"* is to launch another Vim instance. As for the slow down, one possible (and very common) reason is poor use of autocommands but it's hard to diagnose without seeing your `vimrc`.

Comment: Autocommands defined outside a group and without a `:au!` are indeed a very good probable cause of slow down.

Comment: Thanks, @romainl. Indeed autocommand caused delays. Now I see that complete restart and a new instance is the only way to reset internal state. Maybe you should add your comment as answer so I could mark it as solution of this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only viable way to re-apply your config to a pristine Vim is actually to restart it.

But the most likely cause of slow downs is the overuse/misuse of autocommands.

Autocommands are added without checking for existing ones. One consequence is that they tend to pile-up if you don't manage them properly and every individual autocommand corresponding to a specific event is executed when that event is triggered, leading to dreadful slow downs.

Here are the two ways you are supposed to use autocommands in your `vimrc`:

**Method #1**

```
" anywhere
augroup nameofthegroup
    autocmd!
    autocmd EventName pattern commandtoexecute
    autocmd AnotherEventName anotherpattern anothercommandtoexecute
augroup END
```

**Method #2**

```
" near the top of your vimrc
augroup nameofthegroup
    autocmd!
augroup END

" anywhere
autocmd nameofthegroup EventName pattern commandtoexecute
autocmd nameofthegroup AnotherEventName anotherpattern anothercommandtoexecute
```

The idea is to create a group of autocommands that clears itself whenever it is invoked and thus prevents them from piling-up.

Comment: Is it a good idea to have the entire vimrc in a group? Why vim doesn't internally _wrap_ vimrc in an autogroup by default?

Comment: Everything is in a global group, including your `vimrc`. The fact that all autocommands are indiscriminately added to that global group by default is precisely why is generally useful to be more fine-grained in the way you handle autocommands.